# Unicode emoji not recognized on canvas using node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-canvas

I am using node.js with the canvas module and I am trying to create an image with it. This all works well and functions as wanted using local host. When I host my discord.js bot on heroku however the unicode emoji's (higher than v6.1 unicode) are no longer recognized. Wat would be the way to fix this?

See attached images for local host and heroku host.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Node-canvas does not support emoji yet, see https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/760. There's no workaround and no simple way to fix this.